# Sizing issue with CSS / HTML5

Tags: css, html, resize, alignment

I am currently working on a small website. I have a few questions in regards to the positioning, sizing, alignment of some of my buttons...

1. I would like my boxes to always stay in the centre of the screen(✔).
2. I would like to have a adaptive button scheme so that they stack onto one another when the window become small enough. Currently, they get all bundled together and are unreadable  once the page reaches a certain size (picture shown below).
3. I would like my sign up text to be at the bottom of my two buttons. It is currently on the right side of them. Also, when the window is at a certain size where the boxes need to be on top of eachother instead of beside, I would like my sign up text to follow along and go under the second box. Below I will share my code (**both html & CSS**) and I will send pictures of the current state of the website.

Thanks in advance.

***CSS CODE***

```
body{
    margin-top: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}


.ownerButton, .employeeButton {
    background-color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}



.ownerButton, .employeeButton {
    font-family: "georgia", sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    margin: 3px;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 0.15em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

    font-weight: bold;

    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.footer{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;

    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;

    background-color: #2196F3;
    text-align: center;
}
```

***HTML CODE***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Belper</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor=#4286f4>

        <a href="http://www.google.com" class="ownerButton">Sign in as OWNER</a>
        <a href="http://www.google.com" class="employeeButton">Sign in as EMPLOYEE</a>

        <a href="http://google.com" class="signUp">Dont have an account? Sign up here!</a>

        <div class="footer">
        <p>Copyright © 2000-2017 - Mathieu Larocque - All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

[Image while window is large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fxx1.png)

[Image while window is small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERi7i.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `display:block` to a  `.signUp` rule in your style sheet to get that on a new line.

You can also add `display: inline-block` to the `.ownerButton, .employeeButton` rule

https://codepen.io/jbanegas/pen/xXpMKM?editors=1100

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: Just one small question, how do I send the text / buttons to the exact center of the window? I was thinking of placing a logo at the upper part of the page! :-)

Comment: I think you're asking how to get the gap between the buttons to line-up in the center of the window. The buttons are currently centered, but because they're different widths the gap is off center. You can assign a width to the `.ownerButton, .employeeButton` rule. I've updated the codepen to include a `width: 300px`. Please let me know if you're asking something different.

Comment: Yeah exactly! I'm trying to figure out a way to lower the buttons to have enough clearance space to be able to include a logo at the higher point of the window. Not touching the top bar, but low enough for it be to ''clean''. would changing the top value lower the buttons? Or maybe add top padding?

Comment: There's quite a few ways you can vertically position the buttons. I'd look into flexbox. I've updated the codepen to reflect a quick solution, I wrapped the buttons in a container div used margin-top to offset them from the top to make room for a logo.

Comment: You're a life saver! Wish there was a way to contact you but I dont want to intrude you any longer! Just one more thing - is there a piece of code I can add to allow the buttons to turn into two lines when the window is too small for one line? (I dont know if you understand what I mean) Thank you for helping me, this is an idea I've been dreaming of developing for awhile now and I am so happy to finally start!

Comment: I think I get what you mean. You can set your button width to `width:100%` and add `max-width:300px`. I also adjusted some of the padding and margins to be % rather than having them be fixed.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you Joe I really do appreciate your work.

Comment: If I dont want the picture to reach a certain size, do I do max-width? I changed the width to 50% to fit the theme